# Compiling multiple jar and java files using javac

Tags: java, jar, javac

I downloaded a sample code written in java that has multiple jar files and java files. I am not a Java programmer so I am having a hard time compiling the code. Here's my attempt:

```
javac -classpath lib/*.jar src/*.java
```

However this is what I get:

```
javac: invalid flag: lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

What's wrong with my approach and how can I compile the code? ALl the jar files are located in the lib folder, and the java files in the src folder.

Comment: I suggest you use an IDE to do this for you.  An IDE is design to make editing, compiling, running,  and debugging easier etc.

Comment: Which IDE would you recommend?

Comment: You could try Netbeans, Eclipse or IntelliJ CE. They are all free and different benefits.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to stop the shell from `globbing` the wild-card in `lib/*.jar` by escaping it.

Also, you need to remove the `.jar` suffix ... because that's how classpath wildcards work; see Oracle's ["Setting the classpath"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) document.

So ...

```
javac -classpath lib/\* src/*.java
```

---

Using an IDE is another option. However, if all you want to do is compile and run, then downloading and installing and learning to use an IDE is overkill (IMO).  And the flipside is that it is good for an IDE-using Java programmer to also understand how to compile and run from the shell prompt ...

Comment: Thank you! Do you have to call the lib files to run the compiled program to? or should I just run java main.java?

Comment: *"Do you have to call the lib files to run the compiled program to?"* - You need to include them on the runtime classpath ... along with the Java compiler output directory.  This is all described in the manual entries, and I would **encourage** you to read them.

Answer (score 3):

old post, but thought below details help,
you can specify jar files by separating by ; in windows and : in unix

Eg: (windows)

```
javac -cp first.jar;second.jar;third.jar YourClass.java
```

(unix)

```
javac -cp first.jar:second.jar:third.jar YourClass.java
```

Source: https://gullele.com/pass-all-the-jars-in-classpath-when-compiling-java/