# How i can compile my project including jar files

Tags: java, terminal, compilation, javac, lib

I am trying to compile my java project by including some .jar files that are imported into the **SearchEngine** class, but when trying to use the command below, the imports in **SearchEngine** class, such as the **Query** class and the jar import as well, are not found. What is the correct way to compile this project considering the import dependency between classes and the inclusion of jar files?

obs: I already compile the other classes like **Query**

[The current folders structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEXUN.png)

my command:

```
javac -Xlint -classpath ".:jackson/*.jar" engine/SearchEngine.java
```

*[error output](https://pastebin.com/BvxPpJaj)*

Comment: Please read [no pictures of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) / [no pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then use the [edit] link to replace screen shots of text with nicely formatted/indented text within your question.

Comment: Like your command for javac, all of that is text. So, post it as well formatted text!

Comment: And note: there are plenty plenty of questions around here dealing with JAR files and javac. Have you done some research, and looked into stuff like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313812/compiling-multiple-jar-and-java-files-using-javac

Comment: @GhostCatsalutesMonicaC. the picture is not of exception and is not of a code, you not even open... . Anyways, thanks for the link question, i have made some search but i not found the link that you commented.

Comment: Yes, that is a generic comment. Yet, your screen shot shows textual information only. Same story: anything that is *text only* should be represented as text. Images break screen readers, and you should only break screen readers if you absolutely have to.